# riofs keeps failing with 'Transport endpoint is not connected' message

Tags: amazon-s3, fuse, transport, s3fs

I've been using riofs for AWS S3 bucket to filesystem mounting on an EC2 instance.

Yes yes, I know... you shouldn't use fuse for S3 mounting as its a leaky abstraction.

With that said, I didn't see anyone else post any questions regarding this issue (specifically with riofs) so I'm posting this question.

Why is it happening and what can I do it fix it?

It looks like fuse doesn't have a stable version past v2.9.7 so that is what I'm using.

s3fs does have an open issue which I'm guessing has the same problem (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/152).

I have tried adding `-o multireq_max=5` as a riofs command-line option without success.

Comment: the error is very generic, it really just means s3fs/riofs crashed at some point. The best way to debug this is run the process in foreground / under gdb to see what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful. I now know at least which direction to focus.